# Filtering array attributes with knockout. Should I working with nested objects or another way exist?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, knockout.js, nested, knockout-mapping-plugin

Using this http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/NFbxc/ I make almost same stuff(http://jsfiddle.net/uhtshka/HE94X/), which realize almost all my needs, but one trouble still exist. As you can see by the folowing links, array that we use is pretty simple. Kind of:

```
var simpleArray = [
                   {... som data ...},
                   {... som data ...},
                   {... som data ...}];
```

But Im trying to realize same functionality with more complicated array structure like:

```
var notsosimpleArray = [{
     dayname: 'Monday', rows:[
             col1: 'data1',
             col2: 'data2',
             col3: 'data3',
     ]},{dayname: 'Tuesday', rows:[
             col1: 'data1',
             col2: 'data2',
             col3: 'data3',
     ]}];
```

Is that possible to do with saving same functionality?

Comment: I am not sure what is your problem... `filterByDay` method works fine and table only contains the first row where the day is Monday. And also the the Add row button is working...

Comment: Yes, but I need to work with lots of rows, which I can take from server. Thats why I need to work with that kind of arrow, which receive all 7 days. Each day consist of dayname and lots of row. With current code I can receive only one row and I need a lot of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use knockout with complex objects as you describe.

There's some issues with the JSFiddle you referenced (var1-5 set and referenced on the window object?), so I didn't try address the add row function, but I did update the fiddle with an example of using a rows array in the data for each day.

Here's the link:  http://jsfiddle.net/HE94X/1/

Just remember that in your filter function, you are wanting to return an array, which you can find just by looking for the day.  The `ko.utils.arrayForEach` function is not really needed now, because the array is embedded into the object data for that day.

You should be able to extend this logic to the add row function so that it can push an entry into the rows array for the current day.